# Identify subset of data following a given distribution

Tags: clustering, fitting

I'm looking for a method to identify a subset of my data set that should follow a given distribution (and then fit that distribution). I'm attaching a histogram of the data set below.

Specifically, I have data that is Gaussian distributed around zero with a small variance. I'm interested in finding that variance. Because the data itself is multidimensional, but centered around the origin, I'm looking at $r^2$, the (squared) distance from the origin, which should follow a Maxwell distribution.

Far away from the origin, the data set is "contaminated" with a whole lot of junk (making up ~95% of the total data), so I can't simply fit the whole data set. I also want to avoid mixture models, because the junk data doesn't necessarily follow a Gaussian (or any other nice distribution). See the following picture to get an idea of the distribution of my data:

[image: Distribution of the data with the fraction of interest clearly separated]

Now, as long as the separation is as clear as this, I could imagine trying to find that (very prominent) peak of the Maxwell distribution or something like that. However, in other instances the separation is not that clear. Specifically, there is a time dimension in the data set, and the distribution you see in the picture above moves away from the origin over time (the variance in the Gaussian it comes from grows). So at some time, it will be indiscernible from the junk data. This is illustrated in the following plot, which for convenience is plotted on logarithmic axes. The blue histogram is the same as the first picture, the other ones are later time points.

[image: Distribution changing over time]

Now my question is: is there a robust way of fitting this Maxwell distribution at small $r^2$, as long as it's possible?

My best guess so far revolves around that linear increase in the log plots (that's the $r^2$ factor in the Maxwell distribution), as you can see it nicely covers the evolution of the distribution. For a single Maxwell distribution this is given by $\log(\text{density}) = \log\left(\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$, so you could estimate $\sigma$ from the zeros of that function. To do that here though, I would have to know the fraction of relevant data vs. junk (could be assumed to be constant over time and thus estimated from $t = 1$) and I would have to fit a straight line only to the first bit of these histograms. For the latter I'm not sure what a robust way of doing this would be. It comes back to the original question of "How do I fit a model to only part of my data?"

Thanks in advance for any answers / ideas!

Comment: You might have lost useful information in studying just the radial component.  Is your "junk" isotropic?  If not, a 3D analysis can be more powerful.  What do you know about the origin of this junk?  Often such things show up in spectra as ambient radiation, backscatter, etc., all of which has good physical explanations--and those can go a long way towards creating effective models of it, which helps remove it more accurately.

Comment: No, the junk is not isotropic. This is data from single molecule tracking experiments, the "junk" data comes from nearby molecules. Those are distributed randomly around the molecule of interest, but in every instance of the experiment will have some definite position and thus contribute a peak in the distribution (i.e. the experiments are not long enough to average this out). That is why I want to avoid writing down a model for the junk, because it's not sufficiently sampled.

Comment: You might be dismissing valuable information.  You don't want to average out those peaks: you want to eliminate them altogether and one way to detect them is to note that a background peak, when rotated sufficiently, no longer is a peak. But you also just introduced a new wrinkle: your data seem to be a summary of many individual experiments in which you have a *time series* of data. There are many ways to exploit that, depending on exactly what kind of raw data these experiments yield.  It would be interesting to know more.

Comment: The raw data I'm working on are localizations of the fluorescent molecules in a video, so there are two spatial and one temporal dimension. The distributions shown are for pairwise distances between localizations in subsequent frames, i.e. the localizations belonging to the same molecule give the central peak, everything else are distances between different molecules. The variance of that central Gaussian is the MSD of the molecules, so being able to infer this from these histograms would give a way of measuring ensemble MSDs without ever having to assemble trajectories for single molecules